# Как на Python создать в PostgreSQL 2 таблицы со связями между ними

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Начал изучать Python 2.7 + PostgreSQL 9.6.1. На питоне уже есть небольшой опыт работы, а с PostgreSQL опыта не имею. Можно ли вообще создать БД со связями?

Создаю БД следующим кодом, но как добавить в нее таблицы (с определением типов данных) и связями между ними:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from psycopg2 import connect
import sys
from psycopg2.extensions import ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT

con = None
con = connect(user='postgres', password='poilk', port=5432)

dbname = "name_db"

con.set_isolation_level(ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('CREATE DATABASE ' + dbname)
cur.close()
con.close()
```

Например: как на питоне создать в БД 2 таблицы со связью "один ко многим":

табл.1 - `user_name (ID, name, password)`

табл.2 - `additionally (age, sex, hp, items, knowledge)`

Comment: Изучайте матчасть. [Документация по PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-createtable.html)

Comment: откорректируйте, пожалуйста, вопрос, не понятно, какой ответа вы хотите получить. по ошибке - у вас уже создана база с именем name_db, о чем вам сообщает консоль. код в первом блоке корректный, но он только создает базу - ничего больше, подозреваю, что дальше делает что-то еще. решение - удалить базу вручную или проверять наличие базы в первом блоке и удалять, передавая комманду через execute().

Comment: по вопросу в конце - он не совсем относится к питону. да, используется питоновская библиотека,  но она всего лишь нужна для передачи комманд из оффдокументации https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-createtable.html с помощью execute()

Comment: в чём у вас вопрос: как создать таблицу, используя `psycopg2`? Вас интересует какой SQL запрос надо написать для создания таблицы? Тогда спрашивайте именно об этом (уберите всё остальное).  Если вы знаете как создать таблицу, то приведите пример кода для двух указанных таблиц.  Как выразить "один ко многим" отношение в SQL (диалекте поддерживаемым в Postgres) для указанных таблиц это уже отдельный вопрос. (кстати, опишите словами что с чем связано: вы хотите чтобы один пользователь был связан с несколькими персонажами, с заданными возрастами, sex итд был связан?)